# ¿Cómo cambiar el icono de la app programáticamente?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy en la evaluación de una nueva aplicación, uno de los requerimientos es poder cambiar el icono de la aplicación cada cierto tiempo, o pueda ser ocultable en el dispositivo.

He estado investigando [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215774/change-app-icon-name-dynamically) y en esta otra pregunta [de stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android/19593601#19593601) :

agregando los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

y usando el método:

```
private void shortcutAdd(String name, int number) {
    // Intent to be send, when shortcut is pressed by user ("launched")
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Play.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_PLAY);

    // Create bitmap with number in it -> very default. You probably want to give it a more stylish look
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(0xFF808080); // gray
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTextSize(50);
    new Canvas(bitmap).drawText(""+number, 50, 50, paint);
    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    // Decorate the shortcut
    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, name);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, bitmap);

    // Inform launcher to create shortcut
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}

private void shortcutDel(String name) {
    // Intent to be send, when shortcut is pressed by user ("launched")
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Play.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_PLAY);

    // Decorate the shortcut
    Intent delIntent = new Intent();
    delIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    delIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, name);

    // Inform launcher to remove shortcut
    delIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(delIntent);
}
```

pero nada!.

Según parece es posible pero hasta ciertas versiones de android, pero ya a estas alturas es necesario tener soporte hasta `android Q`.

¿Existe alguna librería o alguna forma de lograr cambiar u ocultar el icono de una app de forma programática? al menos temporalmente.

Comment: No se puede eso, además podría ser mal vista, el AndroidManifest.xml no se puede modificar programáticamente y es aquí en donde se define el ícono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La definición del icono de la aplicación  se realiza dentro del archivo [AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro?hl=es-419), en:

> [android:icon](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html?hl=es-419#icon) : Es un ícono para toda la aplicación, y el ícono
>   predeterminado para cada componente de la aplicación. Consulta los
>   atributos icon individuales para `<activity>`, `<activity-alias>`,
>   `<service>`, `<receiver>` y los elementos `<provider>`. Este atributo debe
>   establecerse como una referencia a un recurso de elemento de diseño
>   que contiene la imagen (por ejemplo, "@drawable/icon"). No hay un
>   ícono predeterminado.

**el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` siendo un archivo de recursos no puede ser modificado ya que es de solo lectura, por lo tanto no puedes hasta el día de hoy realizar el cambio o modificación del Icono.**

Como comenta Mark Murphy en su respuesta

**No puede cambiar el manifiesto o el recurso en el APK firmado y sellado, a menos que realices una actualización de la aplicación.**

Comment: Si, pensaba en algo como un método, que permitiera por medio de una función cambiar el nombre de un drawable, ejemplo como que, si el temporizador llego a 0, concatenar el valor con el nombre de la imagen, y colocar en drawable, algo como icon1, icon2, icon3 y jugar así con el valor posiblemente con una función de generar un numero ramdom para hacer el cambio. Pero teniendo en cuenta que el manifest no puede ser modificado, dudaba desde un inicio que algo así pudiese ser posible. Por eso mi duda, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.